# JS: Uncaught TypeError: getJsonData is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function which gets json data from the url

the code:

```
 var getJsonData = function(uri,callback){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: uri,
      jsonpCallback: 'response',
      cache: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
        callback(json);
      }
    });
  }
```

This is how I call the function

```
    var uri = "https://192.168.236.33/conference/sched_participants/0090000146/0090001947/186";
    getJsonData(uri, function(res){
      console.log(res);
    });
```

But it gives me this error on the console 
[image]

what is the possible problem?

thank you

Comment: The function definition is not in scope of where you're trying to call it. Without seeing more of your code we can't really offer any further help

Comment: Side note: You're not sending JSON **to** the server, so `contentType: "application/json"` is incorrect. (But harmless/pointless, JSONP isn't a real ajax call anyway.)

Comment: can you console.log(getJsonData) `var uri ...` and show us the output?

Comment: put the call inside `$.ready(function(){   getJsonData(uri, function(res){....}  })`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, here is a working snippet

```js
var getJsonData = function(uri, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: uri,
    jsonpCallback: 'response',
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(json) {
      callback(json);
    }
  });
}

// On document ready
$(function() {
  var uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  getJsonData(uri, function(res) {
    $(".loader").hide();
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div class="loader">Please wait... Loading JSON data...</div>
</body>

</html>
```